# Density plots for group values with NAs

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a df with IDs and values and I would like to generate a density plot for every unique ID and check about the distributions if its normal or skewed.There are also NA values  and i am not sure how to treat them. Should i just remove them and create the density plot? Also the range of the values between the IDs is different.

```
| ID       |  Values |
| -------- | ------- |
| F1       | 45      |
| F1       | 56      |
| F1       | NA      |
| F1       | 68      |
| F1       | 55      |
| F2       | 23      |
| F2       | 44      |
| F2       | 34      |
| F2       | NA      |
| F2       | NA      |
| F2       | 34      |
| F3       | 5055    | 
| F3       | 4567    |
| F3       | NA      | 
| F3       | 4789    |
| F3       | 5567    |
| F3       | 6002    |
| F4       | 9045    |
| F4       | 9500    | 
| F4       | 9760    |
| F4       | NA      |
| F4       | 9150    |
```

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", 
"F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F3", "F3", 
"F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", 
"F4", "F4", "F4"), Values = c(9.6, NA, 10.2, 9.8, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 
1.2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, NA, 3266, 3256, 7044, 6868, 
NA, 3405, 3410, NA, 5567, 59.4, 56, 52.8, 52.4, 55.5, NA, NA, 
53.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -32L))
```

Comment: Please provide `dput` of `df`.  Also please be specific about the error or bad output you are seeing with your code.

Comment: It looks like it might work if you just remove the `na.rm` argument.

Comment: I think `aes` does not take a `na.rm` argument. Please tell if the error message mentions `na.rm=TRUE` as an unused argument

Comment: basically, it wasn't working at all without the na.rm. Now I made it work, I had to made the limits of the x-axis smaller because the values in the Values columns are quite small. I used this  ` scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,50))` . Now I want to plot one density for each every unique value in the ID column. Is there any idea? I believe a loop is better to do that?

Comment: ```  dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", 
"F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F3", "F3", 
"F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", 
"F4", "F4", "F4"), Values = c(9.6, NA, 10.2, 9.8, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 
1.2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, NA, 3266, 3256, 7044, 6868, 
NA, 3405, 3410, NA, 5567, 59.4, 56, 52.8, 52.4, 55.5, NA, NA, 
53.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -32L)) ``` would that be helpful? @andrew_reece

Comment: sorry about that, I just edit it @andrew_reece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer 2

If you have very different axes, you can add `scales = "free"` or `scales = "free_x"` in the `facet_wrap()` call to add flexibility. Also I just discovered that `{ggplot2}` has it's own qqplot functionality in `geom_qq()` and `geom_qq_line()`. As I mentioned below, this is a more rigorous way to assess normality of your data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# set up data
df <- structure(list(ID = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", 
                            "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F3", "F3", 
                            "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F4", 
                            "F4", "F4", "F4"), Values = c(9.6, NA, 10.2, 9.8, 9.9, 9.9, 9.9, 
                                                          1.2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, NA, 3266, 3256, 7044, 6868, 
                                                          NA, 3405, 3410, NA, 5567, 59.4, 56, 52.8, 52.4, 55.5, NA, NA, 
                                                          53.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -32L))

# plot density of each series laid out in facets
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Values)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(ID), ncol = 2, scales = "free")
#> Warning: Removed 6 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
```

[image]

```r
# generate qqplot for each group to assess normality
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sample = Values)) +
  geom_qq() +
  geom_qq_line() +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(ID), ncol = 2, scales = "free")
#> Warning: Removed 6 rows containing non-finite values (stat_qq).
#> Warning: Removed 6 rows containing non-finite values (stat_qq_line).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

### Updated Answer 1

In response to the clarification in the comments:
If you have many groups to compare, you probably don't want to stack them all on top of each other. Instead I suggest faceting in to many plots in an array. Note the use of `ncol` below inside the `facet_wrap` call. This will control the dimensions of the resulting array of plots.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# set up data
df <- structure(list(ID = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F2", "F2", 
                            "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3"), 
                     Values = c(45, 56, NA, 68, 55, 23, 44, 34, NA, NA, 34, 12, 19, NA, 25, 36)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -16L), 
                class = "data.frame")

# plot density of each series laid out in facets
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Values)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(ID), ncol = 2)
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

### Original Answer

In my hands your code actually works. I put the data here in a way that's easier to import so folks can test and troubleshoot for you. However, if you really want to assess if your values are normally distributed, a qqplot might be a better option. See below for both - and note that the NA values will be dropped by default so no need to explicitly drop it. Also it's probably not too meaningful on a dataset this small but I assume this is just an example to test the code.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# set up data
df <- structure(list(ID = c("F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F1", "F2", "F2", 
                            "F2", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3", "F3"), 
                     Values = c(45, 56, NA, 68, 55, 23, 44, 34, NA, NA, 34, 12, 19, NA, 25, 36)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -16L), 
                class = "data.frame")

# plot density of each series overlaid
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Values)) +
  geom_density(aes(color = ID, fill = ID), alpha = 0.4)
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
```

[image]

```r
# generate qqplot for each group to assess normality
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  group_split(.keep = F) %>% 
  lapply(unlist, use.names = F) %>% 
  lapply(., qqnorm)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$x
#> [1] -1.0491314  0.2993069         NA  1.0491314 -0.2993069
#> 
#> [[1]]$y
#> [1] 45 56 NA 68 55
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$x
#> [1] -1.0491314  1.0491314 -0.2993069         NA         NA  0.2993069
#> 
#> [[2]]$y
#> [1] 23 44 34 NA NA 34
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]]$x
#> [1] -1.0491314 -0.2993069         NA  0.2993069  1.0491314
#> 
#> [[3]]$y
#> [1] 12 19 NA 25 36
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you for your time @ Dan Adams. Basically, I have 29 different IDs and every ID has 30 values including the NAs. I want to generate a density plot for every different ID to check the normality.  If I do that then I will be able to decide if I will replace the NAs with the mean or the median. So now I am trying to find  away to generate all these density plots in a few lines of code. How do you think I can do that?